# Installing a .NetStandard 2.0 Nuget package into a VS2015 Net 4.6.1 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I'm trying to install a Nuget package that targets .NetStandard 2.0 (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions) into a Net 4.6.1 project in Visual Studio 2015. However, while Frameworks should be compatible, it doesn't quite work:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.0.0'. You are trying to 
install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain 
any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact 
the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
```

I've followed the steps outlined here: [Entity Framework Core 2.0 on .NET 4.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394243/entity-framework-core-2-0-on-net-4-6-1)

So I have installed package "NETStandard.Library.NETFramework", and added

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PackageTargetFallback>netstandard2.0</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to the csproj. But, no luck there - still the same issue.

Is there any way to install a NetStandard 2.0 package into my project (without upgrading VS or installing any Net Core targeting packs or such)?

Thanks

Comment: I've just seen that this is a VS2015 project - I suspect that's the problem. It works fine from the .NET Core 2.0 SDK, with a Core SDK-style project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there any way to install a NetStandard 2.0 package into my project (without upgrading VS or installing any Net Core targeting packs or such)?

I am afraid not. Just like Jon pointed out that the reason for that issue is that you are using Visual Studio 2015.

According to the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-platforms-support), .NET Standard 2.0 support .NET Framework 4.6.1 (with **.NET Core 2.0 SDK**):

[image]

So we need install .NET Core 2.0 SDK. And every communication from Microsoft about the preview of .NET Core 2.0 mentions **Visual Studio 2017**, so I think it's highly recommanded to use Visual Studio 2017 to work with .NET Core 2.0.

Besides, the NuGet package [NETStandard.Library.NETFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library.NETFramework/2.0.0-preview2-25405-01) is **deprecated**.

[image]

So install a .NetStandard 2.0 Nuget package into a Net 4.6.1 project, I highly recommanded to use Visual Studio 2017 to work with .NET Core 2.0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, there is a VS 2015 installer for the required targets and NuGet 3.6.0 for VS 2015 supports this. But there are a few bugs still like https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1539

Comment: Thanks Leo, your answer is much appreciated. In case the MSFT in your name gives away you're working for Microsoft, just some feedback: To me as a semi-professional dev (who must use VS in a non-admin environment with only infrequent/packages updates), C# development has become the modern day version of DLL hell. If very simple packages like the abovementioned one have hard-requirements that need constant admin updates of VS, or even the very latest/greatest version of it, something went very wrong imho. I like Net's progression, but compatibility should not be forgotten!

Comment: how about adding reference to .netstandard located in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\netstandard\v4.0_2.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51\netstandard.dll

Answer (score 12):

Referencing .NET Standard 2.0 packages is supported using the following:

- NuGet 3.6.0 or higher for VS 2015 (from [NuGet's download site](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) - may not yet be listed as recommended latest)
- Install the ".NET Standard Support for Visual Studio 2015" from https://aka.ms/netstandard-build-support-netfx (NuGet in VS will also print a link to this in its output window).

There are a still few bugs when consuming .NET Standard 2.0 libraries, especially when mixing .NET Standard < 2.0 and 2.0 libraries but these updates give basic support.

Comment: Thanks Martin. That does answer  the question - unfortunately myself can't go down that route as I am on a no-admin machine and can't install eg the VSIX. Bit of a shame .. .Net development used to be so easy, these days it seems you're out in the cold if you can't update your tools constantly

Comment: I also needed to install ".NET Core Tools for Visual Studio 2015" https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md#net-core-tools-for-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Thank you for the https:// link. It fixed my VS 2015 Nuget package problem with Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.7.1.2. Warning: this link downloads dotnet-standard-support-vs2015-2.0.0-win-x86.msi and will install with no feedback. Shows up in Programs and Features as ".NET Standard Support for Visual Studio 2015 (x86)"