# Roslyn for .Net 4.7.2

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am so confused.. I am trying to install a nuget package that has a dependency on .NetStandard v2.0, after reading [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET) post about it, it made sense to me that I could run any library that is dependent on .NetStandard 2.0 with .Net 4.7.2. Unfortunately, while trying to install a nuget package, it fails, saying it is not compatible with .net 4.7.2.

I am mainly trying to add the new Roslyn libraries [Microsft.CodeAnalysis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) and if you look at the dependencies it says it supports .Net 4.7.2, the issue seems to stem from another dll its dependent on `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces`, as that says it **only** has a dependency on .NetStandard 2.0. (but really .Net 4.7.2 can run .NetStandard 2.0)

[image]

Does anyone know if this is possible or will I be needing to move to .net core framework to be able to support a project like this?

Really it should say it only has a dependency on .NetStandard 2.0 but be able to get installed onto a target framework with 4.7.2 or .Net Core

**Edit:**

Using Visual Studio 2015 and C#6.

Its a rehosted windows workflow designer application (working on c# compilation/intellisense for inputs to the designer)

Comment: What kind of application is that? What version of Visual Studio are you using? What version of C# are you using?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Its visual studio 2015 with C#6. Also its a rehosted windows workflow designer application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46804021/70345

Comment: @IanKemp thanks for this, will try it now

Comment: @IanKemp, that fixed it for me, i flagged this question as a duplicate and posted step-by-step how i fixed it. thanks for the assist man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @IanKemp for finding an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46804021/6414974) that helped me, I will flag this post as a duplicate but I wanted to first post a step-by-step fix for future developers that may come across this.

So I downloaded the latest Nuget version (VS 2015 VSIX - latest v3.6.0) [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)

Then I tried to update to the latest Roslyn package via NuGet package mananger and got this error message:

[image]

The message points you to this link, that will download the .Net Standard Build Support extension: https://aka.ms/netstandard-build-support-netfx

I then tried to update to the latest Roslyn package and it all worked!!

Happy coding all.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for sharing your solution! Just because I see that you are developing a rehosted windows workflow and that the workflow is not super trendy these days, may I ask you a question? How does the WF Designer controls look on your side? Do they have the oldish look of WF4 or the newer one of WF5? I add here the URL to my question, maybe you find time to have a look. Best! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445919/rehosted-microsoft-workflow-designer-ui

Comment: Hi @Razvan, I had a look and mine still has the old UI look but to be honest I prefer it. I have managed to get C# roslyn to work with my rehosted designer and get some nice intellisense completions and even compile error/warning messages sent to a custom window.

Comment: Thank you, John! Glad that C# it is working well for you, I would try to experiment with it also. It was just I've seen the new UI both in Visual Studio and UIPath Designer, that't why I thought it may be available somewhere. Good luck with your project! ☺