# Rehosted Microsoft Workflow Designer UI

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have recently created a rehosted Workflow Designer application and noticed that the UI looks outdated when compared with how it looks in Visual Studio. Does anyone know which could be the problem?

No matter what version of .NET I'm using (for example 4.6 or 4.7), the UI still doesn't update. I have also followed the next article to enable Workflow 4.5 features, but without any success on the UI side.

(WF4.5) Enabling new .Net framework 4.5 features in your rehosted designer application [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tilovell/2012/06/04/wf4-5-enabling-new-net-framework-4-5-features-in-your-rehosted-designer-application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tilovell/2012/06/04/wf4-5-enabling-new-net-framework-4-5-features-in-your-rehosted-designer-application/)

In the rehosted WF application it looks like this:

[image]

While in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition if looks like this (notice the updated colours, icons and toolbox):

[image]

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Mine still has the old one, but I dont think what you are trying to achieve is possible, have you had a look here: https://github.com/UiPath/corewf ? The guy leading this was in charge of the main project at microsoft and he recently made a podcast interview describing his work and asking for help. Im hoping to get some time to look at his work, but it may help you. https://dotnetcore.show/episode-3-corewf-with-dustin-metzgar/

Comment: Sorry to be clear, it wont help with what you are trying to do as I think that is not possible, but I just thought I would raise some other things just in case:P

Comment: Thank you, John! That's where I've seen the new UI (at UIPath), but I wasn't aware of the repository. You can also see it in VS, but I couldn't find it somewhere else. I'll have a look, thanks for the links! Best! ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's an old topic but i finally found the solution to this problem after alot of googling with no real results.
CoreWF won't help with the visuals, just with the .net update.
The solution to your problem, aka to have the same visual representation in the rehosting as it is in visual studio is adding  WorkflowDesignerIcons.UseWindowsStoreAppStyleIcons(); to your code anywhere really.
I added it after initializing the Workflow Designer.

```
        WorkflowDesigner WF = new WorkflowDesigner();
        WorkflowDesignerIcons.UseWindowsStoreAppStyleIcons();

        WF.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerConfigurationService>().PanModeEnabled = true;
        WF.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerConfigurationService>().AutoSurroundWithSequenceEnabled = true;
        WF.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerConfigurationService>().AutoConnectEnabled = true;
        WF.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerConfigurationService>().MultipleItemsContextMenuEnabled = true;
        WF.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerConfigurationService>().MultipleItemsDragDropEnabled = true;
```

I also added some other features you might want to enable for the designer.

Comment: Thank you, Andrei! I'm not working on this project of mine anymore, but I think that after asking my question, I came to the same solution as you. I accepted your answer - the use of `WorkflowDesignerIcons.UseWindowsStoreAppStyleIcons()` - as it is the one that I remember solved my issue. Also, thanks for the other suggestions! :) Take care!