# Reference hell accessing .netstandard with framework VS2019 preview

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I can get my .net standard 2.0 package working in a .net framework 4.7.2 dll if I do the following steps

In my standard project VS2019 61.4.4 right click the project and select pack to create the .nupkg
Then I set up a nuget package source for the package
In my framework project I install nuget package 
I get the following dialog

[image: Choose Nuget Package Manager Format]

I choose PackageReference in project file

I answer yes to accept licensing

Then I can see the following

[image: references]

And I can get my project working.

However on a different machine running VS2019 16.5.0 Preview 2.0, I do not get the dialog asking me to choose the package manager format.

Instead the references look like

[image: this]

and I can not get my project working.

[Update]

After following Lance's link to migrate packages.config to PackageReference
The project looks like

[image: it has an unwanted SNI package]

I was able to remove the unwanted packages by right clicking references and choosing **Remove Unused References**

The program worked!

Comment: Like the dialog said, everything is controlled by "NuGet Settings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go `Tools=>Nuget Package Manager =>General => Package Management` You can control the behavior by `Allow format selection on first package install`. Enable the checkbox and restart VS, this change will take effect.

And note the dialog only appears when we install **first package** in current project. So if you create a new project and install package, it will appear. And since you once installed packages in that project, the dialog won't appear in WindowsFormApp2 any more.

(But you can easily migrate packages.config to PackageReference, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)).

Comment: Actually I found it at Tools -> Options-> Nuget Package Manager -> General

Comment: Interesting that the application only works with package references not package config.

Comment: I guess it may have something to do with the incompatibility between packages.config and PackageReference. Since the `.net standard` is PackageReference, and the project consuming it uses packages.config. You can try add ` <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` to your .net framework project and run a rebuild to check if it makes any difference. And PackageReference is the future I think, so I recommend using PackageReference.

Comment: And I think you can locate the cause of the issue by checking bin/debug output folder. If you have two projects A(packages.config) and B(PackageReference), all consume your package and use some code to call the methods. Build whole solution, check both two output folders, you can then find the difference.(the project which have runtime error should have less assemblies than another)