# Unable to install Sentry with Log4Net on .Net 4.6.1

Tags: .net, sentry

Trying to install Sentry Log4Net version 2.1.0.

Project is running .net 4.6.1

According to their docs, it should work on 4.6.1:
https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/quickstart/?platform=csharp#configure-the-sdk

I can install the base sentry package just fine. But when i try to install the Log4Net nuget package i get an error:

Could not install package Sentry.Log4Net 2.1.0, you are trying to install this package into a project that targets .Net Framework, Version 4.6.1, but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

I meet all the dependencies listed: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.Log4Net

I doubt it matters but i'm on visual studio 2015

So i'm a bit confused. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

My **guess** is that the version of Visual Studio 2015 you're using has some old NuGet client.

In the Sentry SDK repository on GitHub there's a [sample project for log4net targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/5cdb22ac0ef3adf302b4a9a12dd15c364c4f5ca9/samples/Sentry.Samples.Log4Net/Sentry.Samples.Log4Net.csproj#L5) and it works properly.

Could you give it a try with VS 2017 or VS 2019?

Comment: This is correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/46788323/2066474