# When installing EF Core V2.0 why am I seeing warnings against installed references

Tags: c#, .net-4.7, ef-core-2.0

I am testing EF Core to see if it might be suitable for use in a new project.  The development environment is as follows:

Visual Studio 2017 (15.4)

I create a new class library (C#) targeting the Dot Net full framework version 4.7 and then save the project after which I open up the Nuget package manager and type in the following command...

```
install-package Microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver
```

Nuget then installs all of the bits that it determines the project requires.  When I then look at the references added I see the following;

[image]

Looking at the properties of those references marked with a warning I note that there appears to be no version information associated with them.  My first thought was that this might be an issue with targeting Dot Net 4.7 so I tried the same against Dot Net 4.6.2  which produced similar results, although with some different Dll's.  In both cases the projects built successfully.

Has anyone else seen this or knows what the cause / solution might be?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to target .net core runtime to work with EF core?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394243/entity-framework-core-2-0-on-net-4-6-1

Comment: @KristofferJälén  Thanks for the link, that's very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core 2.0 on .NET 4.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394243/entity-framework-core-2-0-on-net-4-6-1)

Answer (score 0):

Include the NetStandard.Library.NetFramework NuGet package, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44409768/909180).

Comment: Had hoped that this might turn out to be the solution, but it would seem that it's not, at least not in this case. Going to try this on a couple of VM's whilst I work through the list of issues on GitHub to see if there is any mention of it there.

Comment: It'll work if you install a previous version that supports .NET Framework 4.6.1.  `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 1.1.3`.