# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.0 on project targeting .Net Framework 4.6.2

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a project in Visual Studio 2015 targeting .Net Framework 4.6.2 and using EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.0.

Now I would like to update EF Core to version 2.2.0 (or at least 2.1.0, need lazy loading and value conversions) using NuGet but any attempt is failing.

Error Message is always: 
**"Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework"**

I also tried in Visual Studio 2017, same error. Any Idea is welcome

This other post [Entity Framework Core 2.0 on .NET 4.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394243/entity-framework-core-2-0-on-net-4-6-1) did not help me

Comment: I just tested it in VS2017 15.9 and it works fine. Edit the csproj + packages.config on your own with an editor

Comment: Thank you very much @magicandre1981. I updated my VS2017 to version 15.9 (from 15.1) and now it's working as expected.

Comment: ok. 15.1 was really old. nice to hear that it works